# Search subversion repository for files over a certain size limit?

Tags: svn

I am trying to locate all files in a large SVN repository that exceed a size limit, say 50 MB. I am doing this so I can later remove them. I have tried using `svn list`, which exported a long text file listing every file in the repo. It is populated with lines like this:

```
 6283 author_name            5704 Feb 22  2011 branches/path/to/file
```

Where the third entry should be the size in bytes. Many of the lines do not include the size.

Is there any way to get a list of filepaths for oversized files, with or without svn list?

Comment: No. `svn help list` or `svn --help list` shows you the options. You'll need to parse the output text to read the file sizes.

Comment: 1. If a line does not include a size, isn't it a directory? 2. You could run a full checkout of the repository and use something like `du -h | sort -h`. 3. Remember also that removing files from the repository will reduce the size of the working copies, but not the size of the repository, as the full history is saved "forever"